# Was it right to convert this answer to a comment?

Tags: discussion, answers, comments

Today, I was reviewing a first post by the user [paveloom](https://tor.stackexchange.com/users/32562/paveloom). Paveloom had answered [this question](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/4125/setting-tor-browser-as-default-browser-in-windows/22432), by stating:

> You should follow Christian's solution above, but I would like to point out that, as of 2021, you need to use the -allow-remote flag instead of -osint since the latter one is deprecated.

I decided to convert it to a comment because I thught it would make more sense as a comment, given that the user just wanted to point something out on Christian's answer. I just want to know if I did the correct thing. Since I am new to being a moderator, I want to make sure that I am doing everything correctly and that I am not modifying an answer/comment incorrectly. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for asking. If you look at the [recommendations on how to write a good answer](https://tor.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) you'll find some advise. To me it is important that a question should be answered. The post by paveloom references another answer and adds some more information to it. I don't consider it an own answer and it doesn't attempt to answer the question. So I fully agree with your decision and also think it should be a comment.

Comment: Hey Jens Kubieziel, thank you for giving your advice on this. It definitely helps.